# Precondition of while loop program?

Tags: logic, algorithms, predicate-logic

I am having trouble finding precondition for the following program. Consider the following program segment:

```
x:=x+y;
if (x<0) then
   abort
else
   while (x != y) do
     x:=x+1;
     y:=y+2
   od
fi
```

If it is assumed that its postcondition is ${x = y}$, then which condition is its precondition?

These are some of the choices that professors at my university make:

a) $x=2y$ and $y < 2$

b) $x>2y$ and $y=2$

c) $x=2y$ and $y>2 $

d) $x<2y$ and $y>2$

Hope for the help of everyone. Thanks for very much!

Comment: $x\geq 0$ perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that program correctly?  Because the while loop is an infinite loop.  Asking for the strongest precondition is equivalent to asking "for what set of inputs does running the program create the output condition?"  And just from looking at what the program does, we require x < 0 and x = y before line 2, so we require x + y < 0 and x + y = y before line 1, which happens to be equivalent to x = 0 and y < 0.

Comment: Btw I'm not writing that as an answer b/c a real answer would use Hoare logic I would guess (if so you should include that in your question).

Comment: I edited the selection of my university professor, I didn't know what formula to use

Comment: None of those are even weak preconditions to what you wrote.  I think you made an error transcribing the problem.

Comment: Sorry! Edited `y:=y+2`